# how to reuse setTimeout

Tags: javascript, timeout

I have a setTimeout as so:

```
window.setTimeout(ground, 2000);
```

it works just fine, but I need to be able to call that timeout repeatedly and be able to cancel it so I would need to change the code to something more like this:

```
var timeOut = window.setTimeout(ground, 2000);
```

and then I can cancel it with this:

```
window.clearTimeout(timeOut);
```

I would like to reuse timeOut at a different place. **How would I do that?**

*ground is the name of a function that works at the end of the timeout.

Thank you.

Comment: Put another `timeOut = setTimeout(...)` into `ground()`, and declare `timeOut` in a scope available to both calls and possible canceller. Or use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) instead.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking now. I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24809987/157247) to address the "reuse" part I think most of us missed the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

In a comment elsewhere you've asked:

> But how would I reactivate the timeOut in a different place.

You can't; once cancelled, the timer handle is invalid. But that's fine, just make sure that whatever needs to be able to do this has access to `ground` and so can do:

```
timeOut = setTimeout(ground, 2000);
```

...again.

Alternately, to have just one symbol and reuse logic, you can put all this in an object:

```
var groundTimer = {
    handle: 0,
    start: function() {
        this.stop();
        this.handle = setTimeout(ground, 2000);
    },
    stop: function() {
        if (this.handle) {
            clearTimeout(this.handle);
            this.handle = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Then anywhere that needs to start/restart it:

```
groundTimer.start();
```

or stop it:

```
groundTimer.stop();
```

...by making sure whatever code needs `groundTimer` has access to it (see original answer below on that).

Or you could generalize it:

```
function Timer(func, delay) {
    this.handle = 0;
    this.func = func;
    this.delay = delay;
}
Timer.prototype.start = function(newDelay) {
    if (typeof newDelay !== "undefined") {
        this.delay = newDelay;
    }
    this.stop();
    this.handle = setTimeout(this.func, this.delay);
    return this;
};
Timer.prototype.stop = function(newDelay) {
    if (this.handle) {
        clearTimeout(this.handle);
        this.handle = 0;
    }
    return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
var groundTimer = new Timer(ground, 2000);
```

Then anywhere that needs to start/restart it:

```
groundTimer.start();
```

or stop it:

```
groundTimer.stop();
```

---

**Original answer**:

> I would like to reuse timeOut at a different place. How would I do that?

It's a variable. You share it with the other code that needs it the same way you do any other variable:

1. Pass it as an argument to the code that needs it.
2. Set it as a property on an object both bits of code have in common.
3. Make both pieces of code close over a scope that the variable is declared in.
4. (Specialized case of #2 and/or #3 depending on your POV) Use a global variable (blech).

Example of #3:

```
// Scoping function to avoid creating a global variable.
// I usually have one of these around all of my code.
(function() {
    var timeOut = 0; // 0 isn't a valid timer handle value, so I always initialize these with 0

    function yourFunctionThatSetsTheTimeout() {
        // ...

        timeOut = window.setTimeout(ground, 2000);

        // ...
    }

    function yourFunctionThatUsesTheTimerHandle() {
        // ...

        if (timeOut) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeOut);
            timeOut = 0;
        }

        // ...
    }

})();
```

---

Side note: Unless you override `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` in some scope, there's no reason to write `window.setTimeout` rather than just `setTimeout`. `window` is a property of the global object that refers to the global object. `setTimeout` is a property of the global object that refers to the function. So `window.setTimeout` is unnecessarily indirect. It could be `window.window.setTimeout`, or even `window.window.window.window.setTimeout`, if you follow me. :-) So just `setTimeout` is all you need if you're not overriding that global.

Of course, if you prefer it for clarity, that's entirely your call.

In pictures:

```
        +----------------+
        |                |
        v                |
+-------------------+    |
| The Global Object |    |
+-------------------+    |
|    window         |----+           +----------------------+
|    setTimeout     |--------------->| Function: setTimeout |
|    clearTimeout   |---...          +----------------------+
|    document       |---...
|    ...            |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to arbitrarily reuse the same setTimeout call, use a function:

```
var groundTimeout;

function startMyTimeout() {
  groundTimeout = window.setTimeout(ground, 2000);
}

function stopMyTimeout() {
  window.clearTimeout( groundTimeout );
}
```

Then you can simply call the function whenever you'd like to reuse that particular setTimeout call. If you'd like to repeat the call in an expected pattern, try setInterval:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Declare timeOut as a global variable, instead of local inside the function. Then you can use it in any of your functions.

Something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var timeOut = window.setTimeout(ground, 2000);

 function oneF(){
 }

 function twoF(){
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: But how would I reactivate the timeOut in a different place.